# what causes the weird "UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username" error?

Tags: django

I try to insert data in user model into other model by one to one relationship. In specific, I want insert username,email and password attributes of User into other models.In Addtional, I intend to create both User model and other model in one form. So, I override the save method in modelform. It works partially and be able to insert data in both models and databases, except throw a UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username error.

In models.py

```
class Staff(models.Model):

  yes_or_no = ((True, 'Yes'),(False, 'No'))
  male_or_female = ((True,'Male'),(False,'Female'))

  user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)

  gender = models.BooleanField(default = True, choices = male_or_female)
  birthday = models.DateField(default =None,blank = False, null = False)
  created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
  authorized = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices = yes_or_no) 
  store_id = models.ForeignKey(Store,default=1)

  @property
  def name(self):
    return self.user.username
  @property
  def email(self):
    return self.user.email
  @property
  def password(self):
    return self.user.password
  @property
  def first_name(self):
    return self.user.first_name
  @property
  def last_name(self):
    return self.user.last_name

  def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

In forms.py

```
 class StaffForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email= forms.EmailField(max_length=100, required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    store_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Store.objects.all(),empty_label="--------") # select values ?
    first_name = forms.CharField(required = True,max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required = True,max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        fields = ('gender','birthday','authorized','store_id')
        widgets = {'authorized':forms.RadioSelect,
                   'gender':forms.RadioSelect,
                    'birthday':SelectDateWidget(years=range(date.today().year-50,date.today().year))
        }

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        Staff = super(StaffForm,self).save(commit=False)
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=self.cleaned_data['name'], 
            first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'], 
            last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name'],
            email= self.cleaned_data['email'])
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password']) 
        if self.cleaned_data['authorized']:
            user.is_staff = True
        Staff.user = user
        Staff.save()
```

In views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/dataInfo/login/')
def createstaff(request):

    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = StaffForm(request.POST or None)
    # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/dataInfo/staff_view/')
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = StaffForm()
    return render(request, 'dataInfo/create_staff.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: The error let think that `form.save()` is called twice.

Comment: Thanks, this is a clue to debug. It seems that something is wrong in my overridden save method. I solved the problem by rename save() to save2() and then, I call form.save2() and form.save() separately in createstaff view. However, I still confuse to the reason that cause the error.  In my sample, there is only one place to call save method. Can error causes by some places beyond my sample code?